# External ID not found in the system

Tags: xml, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I have a Odoo 10 cron xml, which looks like this:

```
    <record forcecreate="True" id="saas_portal_suspend_expired" model="ir.cron">
        <field name="name">Saas portal - suspend expired clients</field>
        <field eval="True" name="active" />
        <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
        <field name="interval_number">1</field>
        <field name="interval_type">days</field>
        <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
        <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
        <field name="model">saas_portal.client</field>
        <field name="function">_cron_suspend_expired_clients</field>
        <field name="args">()</field>
    </record>
```

Which worked as should. I changed the code according to Odoo v11 to work, so it looks like this:

```
    <record forcecreate="True" id="saas_portal_suspend_expired" model="ir.cron">
        <field name="name">Saas portal - suspend expired clients</field>
        <field eval="True" name="active" />
        <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
        <field name="interval_number">1</field>
        <field name="interval_type">days</field>
        <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
        <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
        <field name="model_id" ref="saas_portal.client"/>
        <field name="function">_cron_suspend_expired_clients</field>
        <field name="args">()</field>
    </record>
```

As one can see I changed field model to model_id. But for some reason I'm getting error:

odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: saas_portal.client"

The module itself is called saas_portal, model I'm referencing has _name = 'saas_portal.client' I tried to use `<field name="model_id" ref="saas_portal.saas_portal.client"/>` but with no success. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is changed between odoo version but
when you reference a model you use this:

```py
    addon_name.model_model_name # (.) --> (_)
```

Ex:

```
    base.model_res_users
```

In you case:

```
      ref="model_saas_portal_client"
 # or
 your_addon_name.model_saas_portal_client
```

Comment: I tried to set `<field name="model_id" ref="saas_portal_client"/>` but still no effect

Comment: is your model in the same addon as ir.cron

Comment: Yes, module saas_portal, xml in data/cron.xml, model in models/saas_portal.py Data xml included in manifest, models imported. Although it is not the only issue I have. Experienced same issues in all records, which has field `model_id` as reference to model in xml

Comment: You should use model_  as i said iny answer

Comment: `ref="model_saas_portal_client"`

Comment: Aha, so model_ is important! Thank you, it works now

Answer (score 3):

You should prefix ref with `model_`.

```
<field name="model_id" ref="model_saas_portal_client"/>
```

Or, since your module name is also saas_portal:

```
<field name="model_id" ref="saas_portal.model_saas_portal_client"/>
```

Comment: Even if you repeated the answer but you deserve an up vote it's clear

Comment: @Tchi-Odoo True